# Can't input json object into Dart parser function

Tags: dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm returning a json object from a post request and want to parse it to a dart model. I have already generated the dart model and `fromJson` function.

```
factory Did.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Did(
      id: json['id'] as String,
      docHash: json['docHash'] as String,
      pubKey: json['pubKey'] as String,
      privKey: json['privKey'] as String,
      credential:
          Credential.fromJson(json['credential'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      message: json['message'] as String,
      success: json['success'] as bool);
```

This is only an extract from my model but the part were I get the error `The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`. I'm tryingto parse the reponse to the dart object after creating the post request in the bloc repository:

```
var res = await dio.post("http://did-backend.herokuapp.com/create",
    data: {
      "firstName": firstName.trim(),
      "lastName": lastName.trim(),
      "email": email.trim(),
      "phoneNumber": phoneNumber.trim(),
      "dateOfBirth": dateOfBirth?.toIso8601String(),
      "sex": sex.trim(),
      "address": address.trim(),
      "city": city.trim(),
      "state": state.trim(),
      "postalCode": postalCode.trim(),
      "country": country.trim()
    },
    options: Options(headers: {
      Headers.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
    }));
if (res.statusCode == 200) {
  final json = jsonDecode(res.data.toString());
  print(Did.fromJson(json));
  return Did.fromJson(json);
}
```

The decoded json object is of type dynamic so I can't pass it into the `Did.fromJson()` function.
How do I have to transform the Dio response to pass it into the `fromJson` function?
**Edit:**
This is my model which includes the fromJSON function
[Did.dart](https://www.mediafire.com/file/xtteiip3s4crs0m/did.dart/file)
**Edit 2:**
The response of the Dio post request which is not parsed yet:
`print(res)`

```
{
  "id": "GbLnu9eCQ2sVBiKngNxts6NJMprxRczc63CKaZsiJsGT",
  "docHash": "PNSGTXSGODDBHRVWUTFIZUJT9UMPNM9MFBEMCQBYSIRQTDKXPVUCSPNBCXVNGIFEMWSBRUBYARZDA9999",
  "pubKey": "38aqV9FLAn9bXSPm388LcTronqZabEzpWKQpBZRcpPwP",
  "privKey": "A7cq3Z3eCN573wL4QDPR2UjwnDMML6deTf499RnN64zE",
  "credential": {
    "@context": "https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1",
    "id": "http://example.edu/credentials/3732",
    "type": ["VerifiableCredential", "personalInformationCredential"],
    "credentialSubject": {
      "id": "did:iota:GbLnu9eCQ2sVBiKngNxts6NJMprxRczc63CKaZsiJsGT",
      "address": {
        "street": "awdwada",
        "city": "wdwad",
        "state": "awdad",
        "postalCode": "awdwad",
        "country": "wadawd"
      },
      "dateOfBirth": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000",
      "email": "awdadawd@adwad.co",
      "name": { "first": "wadawd", "last": "awdawd" },
      "phoneNumber": "awdad",
      "sex": "male"
    },
    "issuer": "did:iota:A5STNhet1zgGbbnZCqniokcAdXbZZ2xcE6QWruQmctEs",
    "issuanceDate": "2021-04-24T15:02:41Z",
    "proof": {
      "type": "MerkleKeySignature2021",
      "verificationMethod": "#key-collection",
      "signatureValue": "3RypuceLDTQt1Anb9WdBj7ayPS91EdiYJ6ELPMChgocm.1117tuDcgbUJddXaLoFqvAh8WWeypGnCTuPCDggJ2cMk6AVyJAjHaaCgSmgaKsGa299TxVBqfypgqbjQx1gExf2kkD9XU8ViYhZRVm9dx5qELnVxcM2H5R5YmL6rLn3RR6SbiNSc7XG.22rTApWSHuzuZNFtN75KcsEVqhgzDG3WGoAxs2itVdy99DkKRSVkbCyhJgd1pgAQPPpnt65Sh3m733PsnY6QFojF"
    }
  },
  "message": "You have successfully created your digital identity, wadawd",
  "success": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure of the type, you just need to make it explicit by typecasting via the `as` keyword (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators).

For example:

```dart
final json = jsonDecode(res.data.toString()) as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(Did.fromJson(json));
```

Comment: I now get the error: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast` So my parser function is probably wrong.

Comment: Could you provide a sample mocked `res` for test purposes? With the model you provided, maybe I can reproduce the issue

Comment: I have added the Dio response to my question at the bottom. I printed the not parsed response. I can access the parsed response already from Dio with res.data.

Comment: @JonasLevin cool, the remaining issue seems to be in the `type`of Credential.fromJson: instead of `type: json['type'] as List<String>` you'll have to do something like `type: json['type'] is List ? (json['type'] as List).map((e) => e as String).toList() : [],` (code can be improved, but should give an idea)

Comment: I'm not getting an error anymore after your implementation. I will keep working with it and implement local data saving. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @JonasLevin FYI tried out json_serializable (https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) to see how they managed a similar case and it turned out the result is `type: (json['type'] as List<dynamic>).map((e) => e as String).toList()` so it's basically the same solution I provided; you can avoid the `is List` check if you're sure it's not null

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `fromJson` to be like this:

```
id = json['id'];
docHash = json['docHash'];
pubKey = json['pubKey'];
privKey = json['privKey'];
credential = json['credential'] != null
    ? new Credential.fromJson(json['credential'])
    : null;
message = json['message'];
success = json['success'];
```

### **Edit**:

I have trying to make request to your Api
I have generated model for you use it instead yours

download link:
[Data Model](https://mega.nz/file/yfQG0JjL#UDGDV3qg0c2QFV5vVZ9qP2SQYdHIEi-CsmA_bAdBsAY)

Comment: I have used this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/apn_json2model) to generate my model, it has null safety already implemented. But the modal is also pretty big, 423 lines, so I didn't want to paste it into my question. This is my [model](https://www.mediafire.com/file/xtteiip3s4crs0m/did.dart/file)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to `res.data` type - **Dio** has already decoded it to **json** and you can pass data directly to constructor:

```dart
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    print(res.data.runtimeType); // _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
    return Did.fromJson(res.data);
  }
```

FYI, you can change response data type using the [responseType](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/RequestOptions/responseType.html) property, for example:

```dart
  var res = await dio.post('http://did-backend.herokuapp.com/create',
      data: {
         // ...
      },
      options: Options(
        responseType: ResponseType.plain,
        headers: {
          // ...
        },
      ));
```